# flutter building appbundle failed, unknown error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, snapshot, android-app-bundle

I would like to build google play store app bundle. but I met the problem of unknown error.

```
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                          
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -1073740940
Font asset "CupertinoIcons.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 283452 to 944 bytes (99.7% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Font asset "fa-regular-400.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 63952 to 2492 bytes (96.1% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Font asset "fa-solid-900.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 394628 to 2900 bytes (99.3% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Font asset "fa-brands-400.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 187208 to 3624 bytes (98.1% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 20612 bytes (98.7% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Target android_aot_release_android-arm failed: Exception: AOT snapshotter exited with code -1073740940


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Dev\flutter_windows_3.10.6-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevRelease'.
> Process 'command 'D:\Dev\flutter_windows_3.10.6-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             10.3s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I googled and tried all solutions, but all failed.

I cleaned all build files, and rebuild, it was useless.

Comment: what is your build command? App flavors can cause this error

Comment: flutter build appbundle,
 after I tried flutter build appbundle --flavor prod also, but failed.
 after I tried flutter build appbundle --flavor --prod -t lib/main_prod.dart also, but failed again.